# NodeJS: route.get with traditional query string format

Tags: node.js

I'm using express to redirect my web request. One of my web request takes in three optional parameters, so I have

```
router.get('/function/:param1?/:param2?/:param3?', function(req, res) {...});
```

My issue is that as all these three params are optional and not depending on each other. For example, user can provide param3 only. In the current implementation, param3 will be assigned to param1 variable due to the sequence embedded in the router format.

How to implement something like below?

```
router.get('/function?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3', function(req, res){...});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [**req.query**](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#request) for this.

As explained in  the [express docs](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#request), `req.query` is an object containing the parsed query-string, defaulting to `{}`.

#### examples:

```
// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
req.query.q
// => "tobi ferret"

// GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
req.query.order
// => "desc"

req.query.shoe.color
// => "blue"

req.query.shoe.type
// => "converse"
```

You should not put the query parameters in the routes. You can make your routes like

```
router.get('/function',function(req,res) {
      
    console.log(req.query);
    /*this will contain all the query string parameters as key/value in the object. 
    If you dint provide any in the URL, then it will be {}. */

    /* So a simple way to check if the url contains
    order as a query paramter will be like */
    if(typeof req.query.order != "undefined") {
        console.log(req.query.order);
    } else {
        console.log("parameter absent");
    }  

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but what do I put in router.get? and how does the user form the URL?

Comment: I tried http://localhost/function/?param1=value, this only ends with 404 not found error.

Comment: @Ming : define your route as just `/function` and inside the route check for `req.query.pram1` is defined or not. If there process it. See my example above. If you are getting a 404 then server would have gone down. check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use req.query like so :

```
router.get('/function', function(req, res) {
  var param1 = req.query.param1;
  var param2 = req.query.param2;
  var param3 = req.query.param3;
});
```

Careful not to add a `/` after `/function` as your url will look like :

`http://localhost/function?param1=xxparam2=yy&...`

[DOC](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query)